# emacs org-indent-mode: how to go back a tab

Tags: emacs, indentation, org-mode

When I enable org-indent-mode in emacs and have a document outline like the following:

```
* headline  
  ** secondary headline  
       text 
       (after pressing enter key on previous line cursor is set here)
  (i want my cursor to be here)
```

I want to have my cursor go back to the 'headline' part, and not automatically to the 'secondary headline' part. How can I make this happen?

Comment: That's how org-indent-mode works. Wihtout a new headline it considers the line a text line and indents it. Why do you use org-indent-mode if you don't like this behavior? This how it is supposed to work.

Comment: I'm using org-indent-mode because it makes it much clearer as to what text belongs to what headline/category.

Comment: Then ask the maintainers [on the orgmode list](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode) if they can add an option for your preference.

Answer (score 1):

Use M-Enter (probably Alt-Enter) instead of just enter.

Comment: That doesn't work, it just creates another space for a secondary headline.

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted since you had it aligned with the secondary headline.

Comment: I don't want another secondary headline, just to continue inputting regular text, but under 'headline' and not 'secondary headline'

Comment: Sorry, I believe the body has to be directly under the heading.  You can't have sub-headings then the body.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  It's not an `org-indent` limitation.  It's an `org-mode`, and a general outliner limitation.

You cannot add content to a headline after creating a sub-headline.